# Change windows 10 hostednetwork mac address

Tags: networking, windows-10

I would like the change the mac address of a hosted network under windows 10, I've tried adding the registry key and looked through all the adapter settings i can think of but still the same mac address.

Edit: by hosted network i mean the virtual wifi adapter created by the windows hosted network service.
The setup is just a standard pcie wireless card (can find the model if needed) to an access point and also serving as the access point for the network created by windows hosted network service. The card supports changing mac address, and multiple networks.
I've tried already changing the address for the virtual adapter via the advanced tab in adapter settings, the option is not present, and through adding the registry key windows changes when that setting is changed (i cant check at the moment, can edit later), this had no effect.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The question identifies your problem, but it doesn't provide any specific information for people to understand exactly what you've done so far.  Also, a MAC address is associated with a specific device, not a network, so it would help to describe your setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can change a Mac address of a device in **Device Manager**.

Right-click the network adapter > **Properties** > **Advanced** Tab

Search for Network Address in the settings List.

Change the value to an own value (without : or spaces).

Click OK

If the tab Advanced isn't appearing, then it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it on Linux is pretty much easy, but as you are on Windows platform I'll answer for that only covering as much as possible.

## MAC Spoofing Using Tools

#### 1. [Technitium MAC Address Changer](https://technitium.com/tmac/)

- Allows complete configuration of any network adapter.
- Command line options with entire software functionality available.
- Update network card vendors list feature allows you to download latest vendor data (OUI) from IEEE.org.
- IPv6 support

**To change the Mac Address**

1. Starting MAC address changer will list all available network adapters.
2. Select the adapter you want to change the MAC address. You will get the details of your selection below.
3. In the Information tab, find the Change MAC Address frame. Enter new MAC address in the field and click Change Now! button. You may even click Random MAC Address button to fill up a randomly selected MAC address from the vendor list available.
4. To restore the original MAC address of the network adapter, select the adapter, click Restore Original button in the Change MAC Address frame.

NOTE : This tool cannot change MAC address of Microsoft Network Bridge.
Network Bridge will automatically use the original MAC address of the first NIC added into bridge with the first octet of MAC address set to 0x02.

For further help, Visit [Technitium Help](https://technitium.com/tmac/help.html)

See   [Q1  : How to Change MAC Address of a NIC ?](https://technitium.com/tmac/help.html#q1)

See [Q13 : How to Use the Command-Line Interface ?](https://technitium.com/tmac/help.html#q13)

#### 2. [System Lizard's Change MAC Address](https://lizardsystems.com/change-mac-address/)

- Shows MAC Address and Manufacturer of network adapter.
- Generates completely random MAC Address.
- Automatically activating the new MAC address after the change.

**To Change the MAC Address**

Simply Follow this [Tutorial](https://lizardsystems.com/wiki/change_mac_address/faq/tutorial_changing_mac_address_in_windows_7)

#### 3. [SMAC](https://smac.soft32.com/) ([Download Here](http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/))

- Filters Active and Inactive Adapters.
- View , Generate and Validate MAC Address.
- 1-Click Network Adapter Restart
- IPConfig Button to show network status
- Shows MAC Change Hostory
- `The new MAC addresses you change will sustain from reboots.`

**To Change the MAC Address**

It's too easy. Just Start the tool and you'll get to know how .[See Screenshots](https://smac.soft32.com/screenshots/)

#### 4. [Portable Spoof-Me-Now](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Network/Portable-Spoof-Me-Now.shtml)

- Very Small Size. No installation Required at all.
- JustDrop Program file and click Executable to run.
- Can be saved to any USB or Flash Drive in order to run it any PC with minimum efforts.

**To Change the MAC Address**

Just [Download](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Network/Portable-Spoof-Me-Now.shtml) it, and Run the executable.

## MAC Spoofing Without Using Tools [See this](https://www.top-password.com/blog/change-mac-address-on-windows/)

#### 1. Configuring Network Connections

- Go to `Network and Sharing Center`
- Click `Manage Network Connections` OR `Change Adapter Settings`
- `Right-click on the adapter` and choose `Properties`.
- On the `General or Networking tab`, click the `Configure` button.
- Click on the `Advanced tab`
- Click on the `Locally Administered Address` property or the Network Address property.
- By default, the Not Present value is selected. Click on the Value radio button and enter in a new MAC address.

NOTE : The MAC address is a combination of 6 pairs of numbers and characters, i.e. 40-A2-D9-82-9F-F2. You should enter the MAC address without the dashes.

- Go to command prompt and type `IPCONFIG /ALL` to check that the MAC address has been changed.
- Now `Restart the computer` in order for the changes to take effect.

#### 2. Editing Registry Key Values

- [Open the Registry Editor](https://www.top-password.com/blog/6-ways-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10/)
- Navigate to

> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}**

- Click each subkey (with names such as 0000, 0001, etc.) to check the DriverDesc value that matches with your network card.
- Look for the registry entry NetworkAddress in the right pane, and change the value as your new MAC Address.
- If that entry doesn’t exist, right-click blank area to create a String value with the name NetworkAddress.
- Close Registery Editor
- Disable your network adapter and enable it again. The new Mac address will apply immediately.

Feel free to put in any other way to change MAC Address on Windows PC.